# Disable Fields On Publish Page

Tags: fields, entry

We have a unique problem where we still want the fields on the entry page to be available to view but have them disabled so they cannot be changed. So the editor group sees the field but cannot edit it.

Or

A plug that allows us to show a panel with the information.

Any ideas?

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to write you own JS to disable input into the fields. The [**CP CSS & JS addon**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) lets you add custom code to the CP.

```
$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Field Instructions instead of a field itself?  Is this something that needs to be updated frequently by someone without access to edit custom fields?

Comment: They need to be able to update other fields but the disabled fields are there for reference.

Comment: Then check out the Field Instructions for your custom fields. Also Heelp: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/heelp and NSM Publish Hints: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nsm-publish-hints